# docxtpl: insert new row with borders

Tags: python, jinja2, docxtpl

I have a word document `page.docx` containing tables and the python file `file 1.py`:

```py
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

doc = DocxTemplate("page.docx")
context = { 'text': 'there could be your ad'}

a = doc.tables

for i in a:
    if i.cell(0,0).text == 'some_text_in_title':
        print(i.cell(0,0).text)
        i.add_row()

doc.render(context)
doc.save("page1.docx")
```

This inserts new rows into the file but doesn't add borders to these new rows.

How can I set border settings in docxtpl?

Comment: try with i.style = 'Table Grid'

Comment: KeyError: "no style with name 'Table Grid'"

Comment: Also,

```
for style in doc.styles:
    print(style.name)
```

Gives that result

```
Normal
Default Paragraph Font
Normal Table
No List
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`python-docx`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) module is more suited for your purpose of modifying an existing table in a Word document.

```
from docx import Document

document = Document(input_document_path)
tables = document.tables

for table in tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        if row.cells[0].text=="text_to_match":
            print(row.cells[0].text)
            table.add_row().cells

document.save(output_file_path)
```

The rows newly created with the `add_row()` function retain the style attributes of the original table.